# Getting error while building react-native ios app

Tags: ios, reactjs, xcode, react-native

It is showing the following error:

> The following build commands failed:
> Ld /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName-awsopqzjecltzpfagtnbgevaceoi/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ProjectName.app/ProjectName normal (in target 'ProjectName' from project 'ProjectName')
> (1 failure)

> objc[90208]: Class AMSupportURLConnectionDelegate is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x21dda6b90) and /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x104be82c8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
> objc[90208]: Class AMSupportURLSession is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x21dda6be0) and /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x104be8318). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

Expecting to run without error

Comment: You'll need to post the full error, I doubt that's everything Xcode is saying.

Comment: Post the full log as mentioned above. What you posted does not say much...or anything.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This is another major error...rest all are minor warnings...